# Bounded linear operator between $\ell_2$ and itself.

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely bounded linear operators. In the text, the author gives the following example:

> **Example**: Let $(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite matrix and let $K^2=\sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty}|a_{ij}|^2<\infty$. Then the operator $A$ defined in $\ell_2$ by
> $$
> A\left((a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}\right)=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}a_j\right)_{i=1}^{\infty}\tag{1}
> $$
> is a bounded linear operator.

So writing $(1)$ out a little more
$$
A\left((a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}\right)=\left(
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{1j}a_j,\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{2j}a_j,\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{3j}a_j,\dots,\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{nj}a_j,\dots
\right)\tag{2}
$$

My question is fairly straightforward: what are the elements $a_{1j},a_{2j},\dots,a_{nj},\dots$? I mean each "slot" in the sequence of $(2)$ is of the form
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{nj}a_j=a_{n1}a_1+a_{n2}a_2+a_{n3}a_3+\cdots+a_{nn}a_n+\cdots.\tag{3}
$$
The values $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n,\dots$ clearly come from the sequence inputted $(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$. However, again, where are the values $a_{1j},a_{2j},\dots,a_{nj},\dots$ coming from? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $a_{1j}=a_{ij}$ where $i=1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I see that, but if we only know of a sequence $(a_i)_i$, where are the values for $(a_{ij})_{i,j}$ coming from? That is, to my knowledge, we are only working with the sequence $(a_i)_i$. Or is there some relationship between $(a_i)_i$ and $(a_{ij})_{i,j}$?

Comment: The $a_{ij}$ are just the entries in the *given* matrix. They "come from" the very first sentence: "Let $(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{\infty}$ be an infinite matrix"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is saying if an "infinite matrix" $A$ satisfies certain conditions such that the entries aren't too big ("i.e.$K<\infty$), actually, $v\mapsto Av$ is a bounded linear operator. This is not immediately obvious at first glance because saying that the sum of entries squared is finite is not the condition of being a bounded linear operator. I think usually you define your operator norm as $\sup_{v}\frac{||Av||}{||v||}$ and if this operator norm is finite, then you say that $A$ is a bounded linear operator.

The $a_{ij}$ are the matrix entries of the operator $A$ and the things with single subscript $a_i$ are the "vectors" in a space called $\ell_2\subset \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. The $\ell_2$ space is the set of sequences, $\{a_i\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |a_i|^2<\infty$ (hence, the name $\ell_2$).

Comment: So the operator $A$ is sending a sequence in $\ell_2$ to a matrix?

Comment: No, "an infinite matrix" $A$ is sending a sequence in $\ell_2$ to another sequence in $\ell_2$. Your equation (2) is telling you what the entries of these sequences are. Operators just mean linear maps in this context and $A$ is like the infinite dimensional version of what you did in linear algebra when you write a linear map as a matrix with respect to a certain basis.

Comment: Ah okay. So for a concrete problem the operator $A$, being the "infinite matrix" $(a_{ij})$ would be given.

Comment: You don't always want to write a linear operator in a matrix form (for various reasons like perhaps the basis isn't even countably infinite and so there's no canonical ordering) but the point is that in this question, this is how the operator is defined.

Comment: I think I got it now, thanks!